# How can I remove the second desktop on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-desktops

On Lubuntu, I have two desktops and can change between them by scrolling.

How can I completely remove the 2nd desktop? I don't want to just unassign the scroll shortcut, I want the extra desktop gone.

Comment: Are you saying multiple Desktop Environments

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open the Application menu, go to Preferences and -> Openbox Configuration Manager:

[image]

Click Desktops:

[image]

Click the `-` button, and you will have 1 desktop. You may then wish to remove the "Desktop Pager" in the bottom bar by right clicking on it.